# How do I get the username once logged in with mod_auth_mellon?

Tags: php, apache, authentication

I am trying to set up SSO for a php web application. I have configured mod_auth_mellon with apache to redirect to my Idp auth page, and am getting a cookie in response to the login.

My httpd.conf contains the following:

```
MellonCacheSize 100
MellonLockFile "/var/run/mod_auth_mellon.lock"
MellonPostTTL 900
MellonPostSize 1048576
MellonPostCount 100

<Location /secret>
   Require valid-user
   AuthType "Mellon"
   MellonEnable "auth"
   MellonVariable "cookie"
   MellonSecureCookie On
   MellonCookiePath /
   MellonUser "NAME_ID"
   MellonMergeEnvVars On
   MellonMergeEnvVars On ":"
   MellonEnvVarsIndexStart 1

   MellonSessionDump Off
   MellonSamlResponseDump Off

   MellonEndpointPath "/secret/endpoint"
   MellonDefaultLoginPath "/"

   MellonSessionLength 86400
   MellonNoCookieErrorPage "https://example.com/no_cookie.html"
   MellonSPMetadataFile /etc/apache2/mellon/sp-metadata.xml
   MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key
   MellonSPCertFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt
   MellonIdPMetadataFile /etc/apache2/mellon/idp-metadata.xml

   MellonSamlResponseDump Off
   MellonSessionDump Off
   MellonAuthnContextClassRef "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport"
   MellonECPSendIDPList Off
   MellonRedirectDomains [self]
</Location>
```

I am getting a result when I have an index.php:

```
<?php
print_r( $_COOKIE["mellon-cookie"] );
?>
```

It looks like: `6ce7d6484360f5a98683e0ae87738635`

How do I use this to get the username to send to my application?

**Edit:**
I've tried looking at the output of the following:

```
print_r( $_REQUEST );
print_r( $_SESSION );
print_r( $_POST );
print_r( $_GET );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored in the `$_SERVER` variable in php.

The following php prints all keys and values.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

foreach($_SERVER as $key=>$value) {
  if(substr($key, 0, 7) == 'MELLON_') {
    echo($key . '=' . $value . "\r\n");
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but adding this since I just spent several days trying to figure out why the username was coming back as a random string. The issue lies in the SP metadata file. It seems that the default NameID format is "transient". From the docs:

> When transient is specified, the IdP will return an opaque temporary ID. Opaque means you cannot (easily) map the ID to a user. In many cases it’s implemented as a random number or random string. Temporary means the ID is valid only in the context of the assertion response which contains it.

To fix this, you need to update your SP metadata file and set the NameID Format:

```
<NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</NameIDFormat>
```

This will be placed within the SPSSODescriptor element. For example

```
    ...
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</NameIDFormat>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://sso-example.com/myapp/sso/logout"/>
    <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://sso-example.com/myapp/sso/postResponse" index="0"/>
  </SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

After doing this, $_SERVER['MELLON_NAME_ID'] should contain the actual username.